# Find documents in database by a date (year);

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to make a query to my database, i have a collection with some documents that contains a field type Date, i would like to find all documents where the Date is equal to the year that i choose, what is the best way to do it?

At this moment i am receiving the documents like this.

```
facturasCtrl.filterDates = async (req, res) => {

    facturas = await facturasModel.find({ date: { '$gte': req.body.date1, '$lt': req.body.date2} })
    res.json(facturas); 
}
```

//date1 = 1.1.2018
//date2 = 31.12.2018

but i think this way is not correct at all... there is any method to find all documents from a date?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the way you're doing it.

Comment: hehe, yeah actually it is working... but do you know if there is any method that... for example... if i send a year from my client , the database find all documents in that year? @JohnnyHK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) with the [**`$year`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/) aggregation operator

```
const year = 2018  

db.collection.find({ "$expr": { "$eq": [{ "$year": "$date" }, year] } })
```

Comment: i am tryng this way, but something is not working, i receive a JSON object from my client like this.

{ year: 2018 }

And then i do this.


facturasCtrl.filterYear = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    facturas = await facturasModel.find({ "$expr": { "$eq": [{ "$year": "$date" }, req.body.year] } })
    res.json(facturas);
}

I do receive the documents, but if change the year, and send 2019... i am still receiving from 2018

Comment: Are you getting any error? What is the type the date in your database. Is it of type `String` or `Date`?

Comment: in my database is type Date, but i dont get any error

Comment: Then it should work. What is the type of the year passed from the font end? Is it `string` of `number`?

Comment: is a number in a json object. { year: 2018 }

Comment: You can play with the output here https://mongoplayground.net/p/C5POT20X-1x. Let me know if there is any issue

Comment: ohh, thank you!, really usefull website, it seems working in the web... so i have to check all. thank you again!